# pandas reading json list within a dict, within a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `json` file that I pulled from the internet with the below format.

```
[{'type': 'header', 'values': ['', 'TTM', '', '', '', '', '', '']}
 {'type': 'header', 'values': ['', '2017-03-31', '2016-12-31', '2015-12-31', '2014-12-31', '2013-12-31', '2012-12-31', '']}
 {'type': 'header', 'values': ['Activities', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']}
 {'values': ['foo', '-3.615', '1.734', '38.777', '53.06', '51.623', '76.998', {'chart': 'foo'}]}
 {'values': ['baa', '-3.615', '1.734', '38.777', '53.06', '51.623', '76.998', {'chart': 'foo'}]}
 {'values': ['parr', '-3.615', '1.734', '38.777', '53.06', '51.623', '76.998', {'chart': 'foo'}]}]
```

How do I read this into a `pandas.Dataframe`? I have tried using `pandas.to_json()` but because there is a list, within the dict, that is in a list, it doesn't seem possible to use `orient` to read it.

When I just try to read this directly with `pandas.Dataframe`, it does not give me the `values` in proper `dataframes`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you use `pandas.to_json()` if you want to _**read**_ `json`. Show your code!